# Do files change while passing from ext2 to ext3 to ext4?

Tags: files, filesystems

If one creates a file on an ext2 (or ext3 or ext4) partition, then moves from one partition to another, each formatted differently, does any part of that file change? Once returned to the original file system, is the file exactly the same as it was initially?

Comment: _move_ how?​​​​

Comment: E.g. `mv /partition1/file.txt /partition2/file.txt`.

Comment: The contents of the file will remain the same. The metadata that's maintained by the various filesystems will change in both its values and the types of metadata that's kept. Through the course of moving the file, some metadata that is not supported by each filesystem may be dropped along the way.

Answer (score 9):

The file contents will be the same. Metadata about the file — modification time, inode number, permissions, and so on — may change, depending on exactly how you did the copy. This stuff is stored in the filesystem separately from the file data itself. And the actual space consumed may change due to different amounts of overhead. But the *contents* are the same except when there was some sort of error in transfer.

This should be true whether you're copying the file between devices, or using some tool to convert your filesystem in place. If the file doesn't end up the same, it's because something went horribly wrong.

The `cmp` command can compare two files byte by byte to verify this. You can also use a checksumming program like `shasum` and compare the checksums. (This isn't byte by byte, but the chances of a collision where two files give the same result when they're really different are *much smaller* than the chance of an actual hardware glitch causing `cmp` to give the wrong result.)

Comment: `mv` will try and preserve whatever is preservable including mtime and atime. It may not be able to preserve ownership or special file attributes. Some implementations will also try to preserve sparseness.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Edited for clarity.